# Truffle Test - How To Show Errors Only

Tags: solidity, truffle

How does one suppress all compilation warnings (not errors) when running **truffle test**? Using the `--quiet` parameter does not seem to work.

```
Truffle v5.0.0 (core: 5.0.0)
Node v10.15.3
```

Comment: Do you need to see errors so that's why you want to suppress warnings?

Comment: It's less about seeing test errors and failures and more about seeing compilation and syntax errors that tend to get lost in the sea of warnings. These warnings result from 3rd party libraries that I don't want to touch.

Comment: See my answer @trajan . If you want to see compilation errors use `truffle compile | grep 'Error'` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't suppress warnings, no such functionality yet in Truffle.

However, you can filter the output. I'm going to show an example using [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep).

```
~/your_project_dir$ truffle test | grep 'Error'
```

This will show only the lines which contain the word "Error".